# Can I craft and/or identify multiple items at once in Diablo 3 Ultimate Evil Edition?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have noticed that the console version is lacking the book to identify all the legendaries in the inventory at once, and i also can't seem to find an option to craft multiple items at once.

Am i missing something, or have these features just not been implemented in the console version?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but may I ask what real advantage this would give, in the first place? Identifying items is simple, and quick. I often wonder why you have to identify items, in the first place.

Comment: less time wasted? now you spent 10x identifying what an item is. instead of 1 cast bar and entire inventory is identified. the same goes for crafting. When you have to single craft 500 gems to get to the max lvl you want a bulk craft option...

Comment: Did a quick look on some forums, and generally found people having a laugh at the inclusion of "the book of cain", with the punchline being 'whats the point'. Also found that a majority of items dropped on console don't need to be identified, compared to PC. Could speculate that multi-craft was designed for the purpose of mass-producing to sell to players, as vanilla did have more emphasis on player economy, which was removed for RoS and Console. I dont think I can provide enough guarantee to post an answer, but maybe someone else can build on my comment to give a good response.

Comment: I also have it under good authority that building top-tier gems from the ground up is a bad idea, regardless. You can easily farm high level gems, especially on the console. I have gems coming out of my ears, and never found the process tedious, or repetitive.

Comment: multi crafting was added with 2.2 and from my experience everything needs to be identified when your looting legendaries. Even when you get the same item 3x in a row. I still play on PC and multi crafting is used alot there especially if your trying to get an ancient roll on a legendary craft. You goto go through 100-200 crafts and manually doing that is pure insanity

Answer (score 1):

You can only craft one item at a time and must wait for the crafting timer to complete.

In recent updates, there is now a "Book of Cain" located in every Act's home town that will identify all items in your inventory.